# Table of Contents type control for WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls

What kind of control should I use for a "Table of Contents" side bar in WPF?

Comment: @Felice Pollano that looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx) would be the standard control here.

However, realize that using a TreeView in WPF, while incredibly powerful and flexible, can be a little unusual since it uses Hierarchical data.  I'd recommend reading the [TreeView Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747277.aspx) as well as looking into [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) if you plan to do anything visually "unusual" in your table of contents.